# Firefox SSL and JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, ssl, dialog

I'm experiencing an odd problem where my page's SSL breaks in firefox if I incorporate a JQUERY UI Dialog box.

Works fine in I.E. 8 and Chrome.

I read about an issue introduced by [CSS base64 image encoding breaking the SSL](http://wolfewebservices.com/blog/fancybox-ssl-security-warning-ie6-and-ie7) but I've tried removing the style sheet completely and the problem still occurs.

Has anyone run into this? If not can you suggest a good way to progress in hunting the cause down? I'm currently cutting code out and retrying but it's painfully slow (easier if it was a static element).

The call that breaks the SSL is...

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();

});

</script>
```

So as soon as the dialog box ID is ripped out and moved to the end of the document the problem occurs.

Comment: I'm getting distracted by other things so I've put a bounty up for this. Ideally I'm after a solution which doesn't rely on editing the JQuery UI base code.

Comment: Are you using a cdn to link your jquery or is it local?

Comment: @Julian - what do your `<script>` tags look like?

Comment: @Grillz No, everything is local. @Nick, I've updated the question to include the script text.

Comment: @Julian How does it break exactly? Is there any errors or is it just the dialog that doesn't show up? Does Firebug's Net tab show any red?

Comment: It's the usual 'Connection Partially Encrypted' error, everything still works, the dialogue box opens. Net tab shows everything loads (no red). if you put a delay on the dialogue box opening the SSL works up until the second the dialogue opens.

Comment: OK I've added some test pages to the main text.

Comment: @Julian Is it Windows Firefox? I can't see the problem on OSX/Firefox.

Comment: @Julian I don't get that error on OSX/Firefox or Windows XP/Firefox even if I turn all the warnings on from the preferences. Maybe that commented out css was the problem after all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what's going on here is that the `jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css` file is referencing images that are redirecting to the non-SSL 404 page.

Comment: I've commented out the CSS include to show that it doesn't impact on the issue.

Comment: Oh my, I just double checked this and perhaps it cached the page but this does actually seem to have resolved the issue.  Thanks Eremite. Surprised this didn't show up on the firebug nets tab.

Answer (score 1):

I know you'll get a "mixed content warning" if you have any JavaScript files being served from non-https locations. Try using absolute paths to see if that's the issue. If it is, you can either a) stick with the absolute paths or b) use [relative paths](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200710/httphttps%5Ftransitions%5Fand%5Frelative%5Furls.html).

Comment: Thanks Matt, that is the first thing I checked. I also checked the JQuery UI CSS to ensure it was using relative paths to the images which it does.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: OK I've added some test pages to the main text.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and I found a wordaround to the "non secure items" alert in IE8+.
The alert occurs if you are creating dynamic content with jQuery using wrap() or append() functions, and if this content contains CSS with relative paths to images, or any other external elements.

**Exemple :**

```
$('#mynode').wrap('<div style="background:url(/path/to/image.gif);"></div>');
```

This will display a security alert even if the image is downloaded on the same HTTPS secure connection.

**How to fix it :**

- Use full absolute URL :
  background:url('https://www.domain.com/path/to/image.gif');
- Or use CSS class :

> < style > .myclass
>   {background:url(/path/to/image.gif);} < /style >
>
> $('#mynode').wrap('< div class=myclass >< /div >');